# How to graph jqplot using datetime as yaxis and category for xaxis

Tags: php, jqplot

```
var bar_fan = ['8:30','10:30'];
var bar_ticks = ['a','b'];

$(document).ready(function(){
    plot2 = $.jqplot('bar_all', [bar_fan], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true },

        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: bar_ticks,
            },
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            labels: bar_labels,
            placement: 'outside'
        }   
    });
```

bar_fan = ['8:30','10:30']; wont work. cause its time format.
if use value like bar_fan = [1,2]; will work.
how can I use yaxis with datetime value?

Answer (score 0):

I got his working simply by adding the following to the `axes` configuration:

```
yaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
}
```

Now because yours are just time values, the graph will assume the current date. You may then want to specify either a minimum date or explicitly supply both date and time information, e.g., `'2013-03-01 8:30AM'`